# Application Level Hook for OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, c++, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I'm developing a C# Windows Forms Application using .NET 4 and I am facing a very interesting requirement. What happens is that I'd like to have two kinds of OpenFileDialog/SaveFileDialog: the default ones from Windows API and custom ones with special features that suits my business scenario. Depending on a business rule, the default dialog or the custom dialog should be shown.

I already have my custom Open and SaveFileDialogs. The tricky thing is that I can't simply implement the logic to call one or another, instead I need to hook somehow the OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog and SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog calls on application level so that it shows the default or the custom dialog.

I need it like this because I'm also using third-party controls (DevExpress, for example) and I need that when any of the DevExpress' controls calls OpenFileDialog or SaveFileDialog, the same business rule should be applied to define if the default or custom dialog will be shown.

So, everytime that anyone in my application scope calls OpenFileDialog or SaveFileDialog, this business rule should be triggered to find out the correct dialog to show (default one or custom one).

Has anybody ever needed to implement something like this?

Comment: Great question.  Short of hooking the low-level Win32 APIs (ugh!), I can't think of a good way.

Comment: Yes, from what I researched, it should be something like this... But, how to do it?? I'm trying to use Microsoft Research's Detours library to set the hook, but, I'm not being able to compile anything in C++ with VS 2010 that references the Detours library... Do you have any idea or article that I could look at?

Comment: I honestly don't - I haven't used Detours before but I've read it's a good choice for API hooking.  Maybe post another question about Detours?

Comment: Another option is to look at this book by Richter & Nasarre: http://www.amazon.com/Windows-via-Pro-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735624240 - there is a section on API hooking and the CD includes some sample code.  If you search Google for "APIHook" and "Richter" you'll probably find it.  A word of warning though - the code is incomplete and has some shortcomings: some issues in relation to dynamic loading of DLLs, and serious hard-to-debug thread-safety issues.  (Don't ask me how I know!)  You might be able to get it working though, and it's a lot cheaper than Detours (you did see that Detours is $$$?)

Comment: OK James, I'll take a look on this info... Thanks indeed!

Comment: You are assuming that third party controls actually call the system OpenFileDialog and SveFileDialog and do not roll out their own entirely custom dialog.